# django can't reverse project level view?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to redirect to a view after a successful POST. Not sure why it isn't working if I try to add a kwargs on it. I tried to reverse it without the extra parameters and it worked. but then when I add the additional variable which I need for some conditional statment, it cause an error.

I already checked the docs, some of the issues that was raised here and namespace is the solution but as far as I understand, it's for the app level. I created the view under the project.

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Index_With_Email_Subscription, name="index"),
    path('humongousdata/', admin.site.urls),
    path('termsofservices/', views.Terms_Of_Services, name="termsofservices"),
    path('me/', include('me.urls')),
    path('thankyou/', views.ThankYou, name="givethanks"),
]
```

project views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    return redirect(reverse('givethanks', kwargs={'thanks_for':'registered'}))

def ThankYou(request, **kwargs):
    print(thanks_for)
```

error message

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vcEh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the url for `'givethanks'` doesn't take any kwargs. The *view* function does, but the url pattern itself doesn't have a placeholder for `'thanks_for'`. You may want to modify it to

```
path('thankyou/<thanks_for>/', views.ThankYou, name="givethanks"),
```

or something of the like.

Then your view can be:

```
def ThankYou(request, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['thanks_for'])
```

Comment: Sir! thank you for your help, It works! I wish I have more than 15 reputation to up vote it.

Comment: I'm thinking of not showing the kwargs value on the url and just the thankyou/. I'm concern of the user to use the url with the kwargs even without actually doing the required action from a successful POST for it to be the result page. is that possible?

Comment: You could use a session variable (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/) that you set only if they've done the required action, then check it in your `ThankYou` view to decide if you want to perform whatever action you're thinking of. It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: well let say that I still want to print the value of kwargs but without showing it  in the url. so it's like if it just thankyou/ with the action needed it will present a 404 but if the thankyou/ request comes with the kwargs/session it will print it. but I think I can figure it out with your suggestion. great stuff.

Comment: Well, kwargs in URLs are generally used for resource specification (like the IDs of records in the database or something, or slugs) – I can't recommend using them for functional logic. Either modify something in your database to indicate a user has performed a certain task, or set a session variable. Good luck!

Comment: i see, it make sense. thank you so much for the help and ideas.